# WSO2 EI: Dataservice using giving INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR when calling through REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI 6.3.0 version. I am creating data service within the application which reads data from CSV.
I am running into very unusual case where I have created two data services. One with sample Product.csv which is shipped with WSO2 EI.
When calling Sample (Product.CSV) I am able to get the json response message. but when I am trying to invoke another API which other data service it is giving me below error:

```
[2018-10-10 17:57:31,916] [EI-Core] ERROR - JsonStreamFormatter Error occurred while writing to application/json
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:107)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:597)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:281)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in     CSVQuery.runQuery.
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: InvoiceReport
Location: /InvoiceReport.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getinvoice
Current Params: {}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Error in 'StaticOutputElement.execute', cannot find   parameter with type:column name:Docnumber
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
```

Below is Data service:

```
<data name="InvoiceReport" transports="http https local">
<config enableOData="false" id="CSV_InvoiceReport">
<property name="csv_datasource">/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.3.0/samples/data-services/resources/Invoice.csv</property>
<property name="csv_columnseperator">comma</property>
<property name="csv_startingrow">2</property>
<property name="csv_hasheader">true</property>
<property name="csv_headerrow">1</property>

</config>
<query id="Q2" useConfig="CSV_InvoiceReport">
  <result outputType="json">{&#xd; "Products": {&#xd; "Product": [&#xd; {&#xd; "Docnumber":"$Docnumber",&#xd; "Invoicenumber":"$Invoicenumber",&#xd; "Documentdate":"$Documentdate",&#xd; "Invoiceduedate":"$Invoiceduedate",&#xd; "Customerid":"$Customerid",&#xd; "Documenttotal":"$Documenttotal",&#xd; "Quantity":"$Quantity",&#xd; "Unitprice":"$Unitprice",&#xd; "Extendedprice":"$Extendedprice",&#xd; "Consumer":"$Consumer",&#xd; "Servicename":"$Servicename"&#xd;&#xd; }&#xd; ]&#xd; }&#xd;}&#xd;</result>
</query>
<operation name="GetInvoiceReport">
  <call-query href="Q2"/>
</operation>
<resource method="GET" path="Invoice">
  <call-query href="Q2"/>
</resource>
</data>
```

Not sure where is the problem. Both are simple data service and didnot find any differences in creating them. One is working and one is not working at all.

Can some one please help me. Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a column named _Docnumber_ inside your CSV file?  This error can happen if the column is not there.

Comment: Thanks for response.
Yes the column is present in the csv..

Comment: I have been trying to change the output as json map and it does not work.
later on I have changed the output map to xml and included these parameters 
<parameter name="dsJsonBuilder">org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonBuilder</parameter>
    <parameter name="dsJsonFormatter">org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter</parameter>in the axis2xml file (conf/axis2 directory) and  using curl command I got the response in json (ofcource in curl command we have to add accept application/json as header