# How to deal with Json Formatters in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: json, wso2, integration, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am having a issue with that´s drive me crazy.
Cenario:
 WSO2 EI 6.4.0
         Oracle Database 12c.
            I have a Data Service (VinculoDataService) delivering a 'search' capacity inside of specific table of Oracle Database.
            When I call VinculoDataService from SOAPUI I am receiving correct json answer:

```
VinculoDataService RESPONSE FOR application/json:

{"vinculos": {"vinculo": [{
   "relacaoDependencia":    {
      "codigo": null,
      "descricao": null
   },
   "produto":    {
      "registroPlanoRPS": "410315997",
      "cadastroPlanoSCPA": null,
      "status": "Inativo"
   },
   "contrato":    {
      "codigo": "6",
      "numeroContratoApolice": "APO-006"
   },
   "dataAdesaoPlano": "2018-12-31T19:00:00.000-05:00",
   "cco": "100000001705",
   "titular": {"pessoaFisica":    {
      "cpf": null,
      "cns": null,
      "dataNascimento": null
   }},
   "status": "Ativo",
   "beneficiario": {"pessoaFisica":    {
      "cpf": "06425417609",
      "cns": null,
      "dataNascimento": "1978-04-24T19:00:00.000-05:00"
   }}
}]}}
```

```
 The problem occurs when I try to call it from a sequence mediation as show above.
```

```
myAPI.xml:

<inSequence>
            <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
            <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
            <call blocking="true">
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://wso2ei.coreconsulting:8282/services/VinculoDataService/pesquisar?operadora={uri.var.operadora}&amp;contrato={uri.var.codigo}"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
```

This is give me the **first problem** Error Response:

```
Error log message for wso2carbon.xml:

 >> "GET /services/VinculoDataService/pesquisar?operadora=313149&contrato=6 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,608] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-37] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,608] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-37] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,608] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-37] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,609] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-37] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,609] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-37] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Host: wso2ei.coreconsulting:8282[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,609] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-37] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,781] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-38] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter} -  Error occurred while writing to application/json
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:107)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:614)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:280)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:99)
        at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonFormatter.writeTo(JsonFormatter.java:61)
        ... 16 more
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,785] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-38] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} -  Failed to submit the response
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:113)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:614)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:280)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-11-26 14:10:05,786] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-38] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  Error processing GET request for : /services/VinculoDataService/pesquisar?operadora=313149&contrato=6
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:676)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:282)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:113)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:614)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:280)
```

After some research I found this answer: [WSO2 EI: Dataservice using giving INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR when calling through REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746293/wso2-ei-dataservice-using-giving-incompatible-parameters-error-when-calling-thr) and follow the wso2 EI reference guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters.
With those references I try to config other Message Builders and Formatters for json (text/json and text/javascript) as follows:

```
(axis2.xml FILE)

<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/javascript"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/json"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
...
 <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
 <messageBuilder contentType="text/javascript"
               class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
         <messageBuilder contentType="text/json"
               class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder"/>
```

I had test it from SOAPUI for bove (text/javascritp and text/json) and both give to me the response with little differences. But if a get it inside mediation OK.
 
The follow json show de answer for media types 'text/json' and 'text/javascrtipt'

```
{"vinculos": {"vinculo": {
   "relacaoDependencia":    {
      "codigo": {"@nil": "true"},
      "descricao": {"@nil": "true"}
   },
   "produto":    {
      "registroPlanoRPS": "410315997",
      "cadastroPlanoSCPA": {"@nil": "true"},
      "status": "Inativo"
   },
   "contrato":    {
      "codigo": "6",
      "numeroContratoApolice": "APO-006"
   },
   "dataAdesaoPlano": "2018-12-31T19:00:00.000-05:00",
   "cco": "100000001705",
   "titular": {"pessoaFisica":    {
      "cpf": {"@nil": "true"},
      "cns": {"@nil": "true"},
      "dataNascimento": {"@nil": "true"}
   }},
   "status": "Ativo",
   "beneficiario": {"pessoaFisica":    {
      "cpf": "06425417609",
      "cns": {"@nil": "true"},
      "dataNascimento": "1978-04-24T19:00:00.000-05:00"
   }}
}}}
```

The **issue is using those new media types, I am receiving void response inside of my mediations**:

```
Wso2carbon.log Error message using 'text/json' or 'text/javascritp' media types:

 "GET /services/VinculoDataService/pesquisar?operadora=313149&contrato=6 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,443] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,443] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Accept: text/json[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,443] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,443] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,443] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "Host: wso2ei.coreconsulting:8282[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,444] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  >> "[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,652] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,652] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,653] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  << "Content-Type: text/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,653] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  << "Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2019 18:54:52 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,653] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,653] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} -  << "[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,655] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} -  << "f"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,655] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} -  << "[\r]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,655] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} -  << "[\n]"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,655] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} -  << "{"vinculos":""}"
[2019-11-26 13:54:52,657] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-34]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil} -  OMException in getSOAPBuilder
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

We can see inside last log that the call of VinculoDataService inside mediation get a void message ("{"vinculos":""}").

So what Am I doing wrong? 
I don´t understand...

Regards
Marcello.